# Реализация многопоточности. Поток не останавливается

Tags: java, многопоточность

Только начал практиковать многопоточность. Придумал сам себе задачу:

> Стоит чашка, полностью залитая водой. Каждые 3 секунды из неё пьют 10% жидкости. А каждые 6 секунд наливают 10% жидкости. Изобразить это программно и высчитать через сколько секунд чашка будет пуста.

Я сначала реализовал это двумя циклами, но понял, что это не то, что мне нужно. Как я понял должны быть два потока, живущих независимо друг от друга. Я никогда такое не делал и у меня это не получилось. Прошу помощи

Все сначала работает нормально, но как только поток `drink` опустошает чашку, поток `plus` продоожает её заполнять.

```
public class Main {

    static int cap = 100;
    static int time = 0;

    static Thread plus;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread drink = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (cap > 0) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                        cap -= 10;
                        System.out.println(cap);
                        time += 3;
                    }
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    plus.interrupt();
                    System.out.println(time);
                }
            });

        plus = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (cap > 0) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(6000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                        cap += 10;
                        System.out.println(cap);
                        time += 6;
                    }
                    Thread.currentThread().stop();
                }
            });

        drink.start();
        plus.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас также есть ошибка в расчёте оставшейся ёмкости чашки, да и время тоже. Попробуйте блокировать секцию обновления чашки в обоих потоках через `lock(Object);`

Comment: Thread.currentThread().`stop()`; - deprecated!!! Никогда не юзайте этот метод! Он приводит к непредсказуемым последствиям.

Comment: Вы вызываете `interrupt()`, но нигде не проверяете состояние прерывания потока.

Comment: @ArchDemon, в чем ошибка вычислений? По поводу синхронизации - согласен. Но можно обойтись парой методов: `synchronized void add()`, `synchronized void drink()`

Comment: Допустим прошло 6 секунд. Первый поток сделает `time += 3 + 3`, второй поток сделает `time += 6`. Итого получается, что прошло 12 секунд, что противоречит начальным условиям. Второе допущение: допустим из полной кружки отпили и потом налили. Считаем 100 - 100 * 0.1 = 90, 90 + 90 * 0.1 = 99. У вас же получается 100.

Comment: Да, со временем пусть автор сам играется. Лучше всего использовать время системы наверное. А по процентам, наверное все-таки 10% от начального количества, т.е., постоянно 10. Иначе никогда не получим пустую чашку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Main {

static int cap = 100;
static int time = 0;

static Thread plus;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread drink = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            drink();
        }
    });

    plus = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            add();
        }
    });

    drink.start();
    plus.start();
}

private synchronized static void add() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted() && cap > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(400);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
        cap += 10;
        System.out.println("+ (" + cap + ")");
        time += 6;
    }
}

private synchronized static void drink() {
    while (cap > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
        cap -= 10;
        System.out.println("- (" + cap + ")");
        time += 3;
    }
    plus.interrupt();
    System.out.println(time);
}

}
```

Comment: Вау. Честно говоря, я не знал вообще ничего про `interrupt`... Ладно, пойду читать про потоки

Comment: Да, это хитрая штука. Она не прерывает поток, а всего лишь выставляет флаг прерывания. А как его проверять - это уже дело разработчика.

Comment: Пока я не добавил `break` в `catch` ничего не работало. То есть... `interrupted` это просто какое-то косвенное состояние, которое потоку можно поставить и при `Thread.sleep` будет выброшено `IterruptedException`

Comment: А есть ли обьяснение по поводу вынесения `synchronized` методов?

Comment: Ведь каждый поток вызывает свой метод, нет же ведь такого, что метод используется несколькими потоками.

Comment: @Flippy, Эти метода делят между собой доступ к общим ресурсам - переменным `cup` и `time`. Поэтому нужно их синхронизировать

Comment: Я изменил немного код в ответе, т.к. действительно, немного "недосинхронизировал" )). Если не синхронизировать, может случиться ситуация, когда на последнем шаге один поток войдет в метод `drink()`, уменьшит до 0 переменную `cup`, дойдет до строчки `interrupt()` и система переключит потоки. Соответственно, второй поток не будет в состоянии `interrupted` и выполнит еще раз добавление воды. А оно нам надо?